# How to click on 10:00 AM time slot as per the HTML using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, linktext

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm mb-1 text-white bg-success">10:15 AM</a>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

My test includes following cases

Login to ####.live
Then click on "My Providers"
Then go to "specialties"
And finally pick a date to book appointment
Here is my code

```
**from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
url = "https://##.live/"
user_name = "##"
password ="###"
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)
signin_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In")
signin_link.click()
sleep(10)
username_elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username_elem.send_keys(user_name)
password_elem.send_keys(password)
signin_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign In"]')
signin_button.click()
sleep(4)
tab=choose-provider&categories=EVERYDAY_CARE&state=&languages=ENG"]')
shedule_appointment=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/section/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/article/div/a')
shedule_appointment.click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('12:00 AM').click()
confirm_appointment=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Confirm').click()
sleep(3)
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select**
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***10:15 AM*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "10:15 AM"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='10:15 AM']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```